# How to run an SSIS package from C# .NET 7?

Tags: .net, ssis

I saw the following article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-ver16

but it seems it cannot be applied to .NET 7.

It has the following step

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the References folder and select Add
> Reference. The Reference Manager dialog box opens.

but there is no References folder and Add Reference option in a .NET 7 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the Microsoft support forum.

One of the replies was to run an SSIS package via a stored procedure, and call the SP from .NET 7

That helped

For the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

Adding references from local installed dll's is 'not done'. You should always prefer a nuget package if possible.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is built on the .NET Framework. Until you can leverage Framework assemblies from within core/standard (or whatever it's called) you don't get to use the fancy new language features or project types.